# Drawing multiple lines with TiKz darkens background?

Tags: tikz-pgf, color

When I draw multiple lines with TiKz, the background of my tikzpicture darkens (i.e., from white to light gray). Interestingly, the more lines I draw, the more the white darkens.
This is the code of my tikzpicture:

```
\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\subfloat[(Linear) random effect model]
    {
    \begin{tikzpicture}[xscale=.5,yscale=.5]
        \tikzstyle{every node}=[font=\footnotesize]
        \draw [-] (0,10) -- (0,0) -- (10,0);
        \draw [fill=white,-,thick] (0,0) -- (10,9.9);
        \draw [fill=white,-,thick] (0,0) -- (10,9.8);
        \draw [fill=white,-,thick] (0,0) -- (10,9.6);
        \draw [fill=white,-,thick] (0,0) -- (10,9.2);
        \draw [fill=white,-,thick] (0,0) -- (10,8.6);
        \draw [fill=white,-,thick] (0,0) -- (10,8.4);
        \draw [fill=white,-,thick] (0,0) -- (10,8.2);
        \draw [fill=white,-,thick] (0,0) -- (10,8.0);
        \draw [fill=white,-,thick] (0,0) -- (10,8.2);
        \draw [fill=white,-,thick] (0,0) -- (10,7.8);
        \draw [fill=white,-,thick] (0,0) -- (10,7.5);
        \draw [fill=white,-,thick] (0,0) -- (10,6.4);
        \draw [fill=white,-,thick] (0,0) -- (10,6.0);
        \draw [fill=white,-,thick] (0,0) -- (10,5.5);
        \node [above left,text badly centered,text width=20mm] at (5,5) {Unit-to-unit variation};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    }
~~
\subfloat[Stochastic process model]
    {
    \begin{tikzpicture}[xscale=.5,yscale=.5]
        \tikzstyle{every node}=[font=\footnotesize]
        \draw [-] (0,10) -- (0,0) -- (10,0);
        \draw [thick] (0,0) -| (0.1,0.8) -| (1.0,1.2) -| (1.5,1.6) -| (3.0,2.2) -| (4.0,2.4) -| (4.8,3.0) -| (5.2,3.5) -| (6,3.8) -| (6.5,4.8) -| (6.9,5.2) -| (7.5,7.0) -| (8.0,7.4) -| (8.8,7.8) -| (9.0,8.1) -| (9.2,8.2) -| (9.5,9.0) -- (10,9.0);
        \node [above left,text badly centered,text width=20mm] at (5,5) {Time-dependent variation};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    }
\caption{Caption}
\label{fig:label}
\end{figure}
```

Then this is the result (note how the supposedly white background is darkened):

[image]

Comment: I can't reproduce this. What compiler are you using (`pdflatex`, `xelatex`)? Have you tried using a different viewer?

Comment: Dear Jake, I'm using pdflatex. I've tried using both Summatrapdf and Acrobat Reader. I use the following packages and settings: `\usepackage{tikz}`, `\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,...}`,`\usepackage{subfig}`,`\usepackage{graphicx}`.

Comment: In fact, I printed the document on paper, and it is actually grayish. I'm confused.

Comment: Could you turn the code example into a minimal complete document that reproduces the behaviour?

Comment: Dear Jake. Problem solved. I downloaded PDF-XChange Viewer and the problem is gone! Thanks for your effort!